# Is this an incorrect error bound value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

In Step 3, they are determining the $(n+1)^{th}$ term.  I think the proofreader just added 1, instead of subbing in (n+1).  Is that right?
I think the correct term should be $$\frac{1}{(4n+7)(2n+3)!}$$
[image]

Comment: I think they forgot to distribute...Wondering though, what textbook is that?

Comment: I think you are correct.  There also seems to be a $(-1)^n$ that has disappeared into the aether.

Comment: @DougM. Man...that's a big one.  I didn't catch that!

Comment: Glad I'm not missing something!  Yes, the alternating was skipped also.